# One line of IE specific javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Is there a way to do have only one line of IE specific javascript.

```
<script>
    <!--[if gte IE 7]><!-->SOME IE JS<![endif]-->
    <!--[else]><!-->NORMAL JS<![endif]-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could define a global var in an <!--[if... and then just check for it later.

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<script type="text/javascript">
    old_ie = true;
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

...

```
if (old_ie)
    //whatever you need to do
```

Comment: I like this idea - especially when there are multiple lines of code that you only want IE browsers to run. +1

Comment: if (typeof old_ie == 'undefined'){
 //chrome
} else {
 //ie
}

Answer (score 6):

**Option 1**

Similar to the code in your original question, but with the conditions in the proper location - outside the script block:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //Your one line of code
    </script>
<![endif]-->

<script type="text/javascript">
    //All other script
</script>
```

**Option 2**

Use browser detection to check the browser and version. I recommend http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html. If you used the .js file found at the link, you could so something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(BrowserDetect.browser == "Explorer" && BrowserDetect.version == 7) {
        //IE 7
    }
    else {
        //All others
    }
</script>
```

Comment: the problem is there is just one weird thing that IE is getting wrong in a really long program.  Ideally, it would be good to only be able to do it for one line.

Comment: IE supports "conditional compilation" comments in JavaScript directly. I think that's actually exactly what the OP is asking for.

Comment: @Pointy, Personally, I wouldn't use conditional compilation. It's not something that very many people are familiar with. Browser sniffing seems more friendly and maintainable.

Comment: Well you could certainly implement the browser sniffing itself with conditional compilation :-)

Comment: Again, I wouldn't but, hey, it's a fun thing to say five times fast - *conditional compilation , conditional compilation, conditional compilation....*

Answer (score 0):

Check out ["conditional compilation"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/121hztk3%28v=vs.94%29.aspx).

```
/*@cc_on @*/
/*@if (@_jscript_version >= 1)
   alert("Hello from Internet Explorer!");
   /*@else @*/
   alert("Not Internet Explorer! Yaay!");
/*@end @*/
```

The code after the "if" part looks like a comment to all browsers except IE.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<!--[if IE ]><script>alert('ok')</script> <![endif]-->
```